# C# , NHibernate multiple where conditions in session.QueryOver

Tags: c#, linq, where-clause, queryover

I am using multiple where conditions but count of rows returned is not correct if i comment out last 2 where conditions it returns right not able to figure out how to add multiple `Where`.

```
if (CustomFilter!= null)
       {
       int rowcount = session.QueryOver<clsCountryData>()
         .Select(Projections.Count(Projections.Id()))
         .Where(Restrictions.In("Countries",CustomFilter.SelectedCountriess))
         .Where(Restrictions.Eq("OrderType", CustomFilter.OrderType))
         .Where(Restrictions.Between("OrderTime", CustomFilter.OrderDateFrom , CustomFilter.OrderDateTo))
         .FutureValue<int>().Value;
       }
```

Comment: What do you expect? Do you only want data that matches all three criteria at the same time? Or do you want data that matches at least one of the three criteria?

Comment: All three criteria should be matched.

Comment: And what is it actually doing?

Comment: If I add 1 where condition it calculates the rowcount correctly (e-g number of rows 10) but when I include 2nd and 3rd where conditions the rowcount returns 0 (which should not be 0) I am not what mistake am making...

Comment: That simply means that there is not a single row that satisfies all three conditions.

Comment: Well I thought that but the dataset in the grid filters properly and returns data from the same conditions though :).. I guess I might be making mistakes elsewhere if the code above is right.  Is there a way i can insert if blocks between Where ?

Comment: dam this never got answered?