# NHIBERNATE WHERE and Multiple OR clause of IQUERYOVER

Tags: c#-4.0, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, linq-to-nhibernate

Hi: I tried looking at other posts. I apologize in advance if this is a duplicate post.

The sql query is something like this:

```
select * from ApiData where BrandID = 'SOUPBRAND' and Culture = 'de-de'
or 
( BrandID = 'SOUPBRAND' and Culture = 'pt-br' and EntityType = 'contactus')
or
(BrandID = 'examplefoods')
```

What would the nhibernate query look like?

This is what I have so far:

```
var mainQuery = _session.QueryOver<ApiData>();

            foreach (var brandPermission in permissions)
            {
                var query = _session.QueryOver<ApiData>();
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(brandPermission.Culture) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(brandPermission.Publication))
                {
                    query = query.Where(a => (a.Culture == brandPermission.Culture)
                                           && (a.Publication == brandPermission.Publication)); //FetchEntries(apiUser.DefaultCulture, apiUser.Publication);
                }
                else if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(brandPermission.Culture))
                {
                    query = query.Where(a => (a.Culture == brandPermission.Culture)); //FetchEntries(apiUser.DefaultCulture);
                }

                query = query.Where(a => a.BrandId == brandPermission.BrandId);

//Here I would like to add
// mainQuery.AddORRestriction(query);
}
```

Just dont know how to achieve it. Saw a link :http://www.methodicmadness.com/2012/04/extending-queryover-with-or.html but didnt help.

Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

thanks to: https://www.google.com/url?q=http://ayende.com/blog/4023/nhibernate-queries-examples&usd=2&usg=AFQjCNG43MDXKhjZ9LrCVSldeZuruBSdQQ
and to: https://www.google.com/url?q=https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14478430/c-sharp-nhibernate-multiple-where-conditions-in-session-queryover&usd=2&usg=AFQjCNHRKbQz3EKGqOOh0gSV0LW2taSX-w

I got the following solution:

```
 var mainQuery = _session.QueryOver<ApiData>();

    var holdOr = Restrictions.Disjunction();
    foreach (var brandPermission in permissions)
    {
        var query = _session.QueryOver<ApiData>();
        var holdAnd = Restrictions.Conjunction();
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(brandPermission.Culture) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(brandPermission.Publication))
        {
            holdAnd.Add(Restrictions.Eq("Culture", brandPermission.Culture));
            holdAnd.Add(Restrictions.Eq("Publication", brandPermission.Publication));
        }
        else if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(brandPermission.Culture))
        {
            holdAnd.Add(Restrictions.Eq("Culture", brandPermission.Culture));
        }

        holdAnd.Add(Restrictions.Eq("BrandId", brandPermission.BrandId));

        holdOr.Add(holdAnd);
    }
    mainQuery.Where(holdOr);
```